# Chrome push notifications Device endpoint error getting 401 unauthorization error

Tags: google-chrome, notifications, push

I have a site which is trying to implement the push notifications. I have registered a project with google dev console and have the manifest.json . But from my index.html the manifest.json is giving the following errors

1)Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)
2) Manifest parsing error: Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token.
3) Unable to subscribe to push. DOMException: Registration failed - no sender id provided

Do i need to do anything from the google project registration side??
or should i do anything from my server side?
The site is running in .Net Server and i have mime type .json

Answer (score 2):

The combination of

> 1) Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)"

and

> 2) Manifest parsing error: Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token.

indicates that something (HTTPAuth?) is blocking the browser's request for the `manifest.json` file, and it's attempting to parse whatever the server is returning as a 401 response (which won't be JSON...).  If the browser can't download the `manifest.json` file, you can't expect anything to work after that.

Answer (score -1):

Arguably the most important part of this is the "Manifest parsing error: Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token"

This means your manifest.json file is invalid - i.e. it's not valid JSON.

Try running it through this for more info: https://manifest-validator.appspot.com/

Once this has been fixed, it will allow Chrome to find your gcm_sender_id and fix the other two problems.